# Faster way to remove all entries from mongodb collection by dropping collection and recreating schema

Tags: mongodb, drop

When I want to remove all objects from my mongoDB collection `comments` I do this with this command:

```
mongo $MONGODB_URI --eval 'db.comments.deleteMany({});'
```

However, this is super slow when there are millions of records inside the collection.

In a relational db like Postgres I'd simply copy the structure of the collection, create a `comments2` collection, drop the `comments` collection, and rename `comments2` to `comments`.

Is this possible to do in MongoDB as well?
Or are there any other tricks to speed up the progress?

Comment: You can drop a collection and create a new one -  there is no similar command to copy the structure from one collection to another. But, you can use `mongodump` and `mongorestore` to copy the collection without data and restore later.

Comment: Since the collection has no structure (the inserted document does), you could simply delete it, and create a new collection. You just have to recreate the indexes.

Comment: You can try this [Clone Collection in Same MongoDB](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/259827/clone-collection-in-mongodb-in-the-same-db/259931#259931).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks, the answers inspired my own solution. I forgot that MongoDB doesn't have a schema like a relationalDB.

So what I did is this:

## 1. dump an empty collection + the indexes of the collection

```
mongodump --host=127.0.0.1 --port=7001 --db=coral --collection=comments --query='{"id": "doesntexist"}'  --out=./dump
```

This will create a folder ./dump with the contents `comments.bson` (empty) and `comments.metadata.json`

## 2. Drop the `comments` collection

```
mongo mongodb://127.0.0.1:7001/coral --eval 'db.comments.drop();'
```

## 3. Import new data `new_comments.json` (different from comments.bson)

```
mongoimport --uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:7001/coral --file=new_comments.json --collection comments --numInsertionWorkers 12
```

This is way faster than first adding the indexes, and then importing.

## 4. Add indexes back

```
mongorestore --uri=mongodb://127.0.0.1:7001/coral --dir dump/coral --nsInclude coral.comments --numInsertionWorkersPerCollection 12
```

Note that `--numInsertionWorkers` speeds up to process by dividing the work over 12 cpus.
How many cpus do you have can be found on OSx with:

```
sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

Comment: MongoDB has the _option_ to have a pre-defined schema - its called as [Schema Validation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/). This can be used to create a collection.

Answer (score 1):

db.cities.aggregate([{ $match: {} }, { $out: "collection2" }]) in case you can login to the mongo prompt and simply drop the previous collection.
Otherwise, the approach you have posted is the one.

mongoexport.exe /host: /port: /db:test /collection:collection1 /out:collection1.json
mongoimport.exe /host: /port: /db:test /collection:collection2 /file:collection1.json

Thanks,
Neha

Answer (score 0):

For mongodb version >=4.0 you can do this via [db.comments.renameCollection("comments2")](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.renameCollection/) ,but it is kind of resource intensive operation and for bigger collections better you do mongodump/mongorestore. So the best action steps are:

```
 mongodump -d x -c comments -out dump.bson
 >use x
 >db.comments.drop()
 mongorestore -d x -c comments2  dump.bson
```

Plese, note deleteMany({}) is even more resource intensive operation since it will create oplog single entry for every document you delete and propagate to all replicaSet members.